# Remove column names from string

Tags: c#, csv

Sorry for the dumb question, but I am having a bit of trouble with this. I would like to return 
"James, Sam, Amanda"

but I am getting
"{ nameA = James, nameB = Sam, NameC = Amanda },"

Little help for a slow guy?

```
 string str = String.Join(",", lst.Select(s => new { s.nameA, s.nameB, s.nameC }));
```

Comment: `lst.Select(s => s.nameA +"," + s.nameB + "," + s.nameC)` :)

Comment: just for reference you are creating an anonymous type and not a string; Other users have already answered how you can get a string

Comment: @L.B I can't believe I missed that, but I used your answer if you want to post it, I will check it. ":)" is giving me an error though LOL.

Comment: What is `lst`'s type? What is the expected output if you have more than one item (assuming it's an enumerable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.Join concatenates all the elements of a **string array**, using the delimiter you provide.

So, just send your list to an array:

```
string str = String.Join(",",lst.ToArray());
```

Also:

```
string str = String.Join(",",  new[] { s.nameA, s.nameB, s.nameC });
```

Comment: @user2525463 Great! Glad it worked for you.  Dont forget to upvote if you can.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a list of string
you can do

```
string str = String.Join(",",lst.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

if `lst` contains your names, you just need

```
string str = String.Join(", ", lst.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `string.Format` instead of.

```
 string result = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", lst.ToArray());
```